# Problems with Installation of ROS-Groovy in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

On a fresh install of ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal, there are unmet dependencies. I have verified that my sources.list.d file is properly set and updated.

I have been trying to search the root cause of this but it is not clear what I need to do.

This is what I get:
vmrguser@vmrg-xps-15:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-groovy-desktop-full : Depends: ros-groovy-nodelet-core (= 1.7.14-0quantal-20130126-0955-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-navigation-tutorials (= 0.1.1-s1359209339~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-filters (= 1.6.0-s1359193811~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1359207803~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-qt-gui-core (= 0.2.12-0quantal-20130126-0207-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-perception-pcl (= 1.0.26-0quantal-20130126-1140-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-common-plugins (= 0.2.10-0quantal-20130126-1008-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-pluginlib (= 1.9.17-0quantal-20130126-0115-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-image-pipeline (= 1.10.3-0quantal-20130126-1142-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-robot-plugins (= 0.2.8-0quantal-20130126-1015-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-image-common (= 1.10.0-0quantal-20130126-0943-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1359194806~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.17-0quantal-20130126-0958-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-visualization-tutorials (= 0.7.3-s1359195079~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-laser-pipeline (= 1.5.5-s1359203953~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo (= 1.7.9-s1359201147~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-rviz (= 1.9.20-0quantal-20130126-0940-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-diagnostics (= 1.7.9-0quantal-20130126-0941-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-groovy-navigation (= 1.10.1-s1359205612~quantal) but it is not going to be installed
W: No priority (or zero) specified for pin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53747/problems-with-installation-of-ros-groovy-in-ubuntu-12.10/) by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try the solution posted [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/53720/groovy-unmet-dependencies-ubuntu-1204-precise/?answer=53748#post-id-53748).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0